# What does this line of VB code do?

Tags: vb.net

I can't wrap my head around this code I found in an old project that someone else wrote. I'm not a VB person. Didn't have a lot of luck Googling this syntax. Can anyone explain it to me, particularly the `True : bool = false` bit?

```
 If drpdnTeam.Text = "" Then lblTeam.Visible = True : bool = False Else lblTeam.Visible = False
```

Comment: Assault them with a hammer.  The `:` is a line continuation, used in this case presumably to avoid the need for writing `end if`

Comment: This person left the company a while back. I'm having to rewrite almost everything they did. Believe me, I want to assault them with a hammer.

Comment: Code readability is worth more than making one liners!

Comment: @AlexK. the colon is a statement separator, just like semicolon in C#. Line continuation in VB is `space + underscore` and has been largely eliminated.

Comment: Google is your friend, only about 3 million results...

Comment: Yes but none I found using this strange syntax

Comment: It's not strange, when you lookup the **(:)** it will tell you what it is. You were asking what it is. My rule of thumb: nothing is wrong with using the colon to combine statements. It depends on the context as long as it doesn't reduce the readability; in your case it does reduce readability and shouldn't be used.

Comment: If you had set a breakpoint and watched the code execute, you would have seen it treat each segment after a *`:`* as an individual statement; that along with the IF Then Else keywords should have made clear what it does.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll try to debug next time and see what happpenss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:` is a statement separator. So another way of writing this code is:

```
If drpdnTeam.Text = "" Then 
    lblTeam.Visible = True
    bool = False
Else
    lblTeam.Visible = False
End If
```

`bool` is probably just a variable (or property) and the value `False` is assigned to it.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. Unlike any of the code in this project! :) Will accept as answer later this evening.